# "psutil.Process(PARENT_PID).cpu_percent(interval=0)" returns only "0.0" in multiprocessing subprocess

Tags: multiprocessing, cpu-usage, pid, monitor, psutil

I have a resource demanding task and I want to monitor CPU usage of the process. I need the cpu percentage to refresh at a high and **constant** rate, which means that just adding `print(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=0))` at various points **inside** the task is **not** a solution. I tried adding a parallel process with a timed loop, that measures the resource usage of the main process and prints it. I attempted to pass the PID of the main process to the subprocess and use it to get the usage just of the main process, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I came up with:

```
system_monitor(process_pid):
    while True:
        # Timer (waits for the right time to start the loop)
        [...]

        # Print CPU usage
        print(psutil.Process(process_pid).cpu_percent(interval=0))


main():
    process_pid = os.getpid()
    parallel_process = Process(target=system_monitor, args=(process_pid,))

    # Set as daemon so it stops when main process stops
    parallel_process.daemon = True

    parallel_process.start()

    # Resource demanding task
    [...]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code only outputs `0.0` as if it did not remember the last call of the function and it restarted the count every time. I also tried the same code but with RAM usage (`psutil.Process(process_pid).memory_info().rss`) and it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you're still looking for the answer, but I was having the same problem and I think I figured this out.
It does not work because you are re-creating the process everytime you call `print(psutil.Process(process_pid).cpu_percent(interval=0))`.

Instead, you should create the process object once with `p = psutil.Process(process_pid)` and then you will be able to call `p.cpu_percent(interval=0))` (excluding the first call that [will always return 0](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_percent)).

I think the reason it is working with `psutil.Process(process_pid).memory_info().rss` is because `memory_info()` does not work the same way as `cpu_percent()`. `memory_info()` gives you real time memory usage while `cpu_percent(interval=0)` gives you percentage since last call (unless you passed [a value greater than 0 to interval](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_percent)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much Quentin, it worked. Basically you need to get all the process handles once from psutil and run the cpu_percent on it once. Then in a loop, you can use the psutil process handles and call cpu_percent. The first sample was 0.0, but the rest of the cpu_percent were relevant values > 0.0